# Where would a time counter thread be placed in an MVC structured Java Swing app?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, model-view-controller, timer

I am building this Java game with a MVC structure that needs to have a timer to count the seconds since the user has been in the game. From what i've gathered, such a timer would be created using a [thread object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html). I currently have classes for the `Model`, the `Controller`, the `View` in place as well as several classes for different GUI components, and a separate class that only runs the game (`main()`).

Where should I, in theory, place the timer runnable thread within the architecture? Or should I make a new class?

Comment: A timer is part of the controller.  I create a separate Runnable class for a game timer.

Comment: It's your design and you decide where it belongs. You could argue that seconds in game is a model property that changes on it's own (while the controller would start the timer), or that it is part of the controller's responsibility to change it, or maybe (that's pretty difficult to argue) it could be part of how the view translates the model.